# Can't create maven project from console on Windows - error

Tags: java, maven, runtime-error

I tried to generate maven project in Windows XP.

I created folder with `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>selenium.web.driver</groupId>
    <artifactId>OMS_selenium_Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>selenium_tests</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
            <scope></scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Opened `cmd` and going into this folder.

Run the next command:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Admintemp\maven_test>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=
selenium.web.driver -DartifactId=OMS_selenium_Test -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dinte
ractiveMode=false
```

Instead of generating project with this data I caught next errror:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2
.2:generate (default-cli) on project OMS_selenium_Test: Unable to add module to
the current project as it is not of packaging type 'pom' -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

Why this exactly happen?
Maybe I miss smt, but I can't figure out what exactly...

- ***How to solve this trouble and generate project with maven?***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your mistake has been to create a POM file by hand. Maven will do this automatically when you run the command you attempted. Delete your POM file and try running the command again.

*Maven assumed you wanted to add a sub-module to an existing Maven project. This failed because your existing POM file was "jar" project (e.g. normal Java code) when it was expecting a "pom" project.*

Comment: I did this and now I have: `[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM
 in this directory (C:\Documents and Settings\Admintemp\maven_test). Please veri
fy you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:`

Comment: my command was: `C:\Documents and Settings\Admintemp\maven_test>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=
selenium.web.driver -DartifactId=OMS_selenium_Test -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dinte
ractiveMode= false`

Answer (score 3):

This happens when you run the **generate** command from within the same folder where you ran the mvn archetype:create-from-project from (or in this case, the POM you generated made maven think this was an existing project).

Ernestas answer worked because they switched to a different folder and ran the same command.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried the following commands and it worked for me:

```
> cd C:\Temp
> mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=selenium.web.driver -DartifactId=OMS_selenium_Test -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DinteractiveMode=false
```

EDIT
Now I have my project in: C:\Temp\OMS_selenium_Test

Comment: Is this the exact same command the OP executed? It looks the same, but I'm wondering if I've missed a subtle variation.